# How do I activate and use "drag cell's corner" Google Sheets feature from keyboard?

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

By grabbing and gragging a "+" at the bottom right of the selected ranges of cells, I can extend the range, copying values or formulas.

How do I do similar action, but without dragging mouse cursor all the way to large row or column number? I want to type resulting range from keyboard.

There are "fill down" (Ctrl+D) or "fill right" (Ctrl+R) things, but they implicitly calculate resulting range. I expect a pop up (like in "Go to range" action) where I can type the specific range to fill (not just duplicate, but use auto-increment, suggested fills and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select the desired range using only the keyboard - use the keyboard shortcut **Ctrl+J**, enter the desired range and press Enter.

[image: Ctrl+J - Name Box]

Here is a sequence of steps that simulates drag-by-corner from keyboard:

1. Copy the cell or range of cells to clipboard (**Ctrl+С** or **Ctrl+Insert**);
2. Select new range of cells using the **Ctrl+J** feature described above;
3. Paste **Ctrl+V**, Paste Special Values **Ctrl+Shift+V**, or Paste Special Formats **Ctrl+Alt+V**.

Comment: Thanks.
Instructions should also mention copying (Ctrl+C) cells prior to adjusting selection with Ctrl+J. Corner drag does not include explicit copying.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a feature in Google Sheets that would let you enter a range reference in a dialog box and fill that range with the contents of some cell. If you really need that feature, you could implement it in Google Apps Script. See [Apps Script at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info).